# how to use angular angle pie chart with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, charts, chart.js

I have put my data in the correct format for the pie charts. i have the array of objects inside the json that is populating my ng-repeat. I am getting a syntax error with the expression inside that data attribute.
error

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{subdivision.chartBldArry}}] starting at [{subdivision.chartBldArry}}].

view

```
  <div class="col-xs-1 p-r-0 ">
                        <canvas doughnutchart options="mapSubCtrl.doughnutOptions" data="{{subdivision.chartBldArry}}" height="40"></canvas>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 p-r-0 ">
                        <canvas doughnutchart options="mapSubCtrl.doughnutOptions" data="{{subdivision.chartInvArry}}" height="40"></canvas>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 p-r-0 ">
                        <canvas doughnutchart options="mapSubCtrl.doughnutOptions" data="{{subdivision.chartLoeArry}}" height="40"></canvas>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 p-r-0 ">
                        <canvas doughnutchart options="mapSubCtrl.doughnutOptions" data="{{subdivision.chartLotsArry}}" height="40"></canvas>
                    </div>
```

json for ng-repeat

```
[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"id":122641,"name":"Green Acres (TH)","status":"Act 4Q07","show":false,"territoryId":2002},"metrics":{"bld":{"type":"Unknown","count":{"prod":0,"custom":0}},"inv":{"fut":0,"vdl":12,"mod":2,"fin":18,"uc":7,"total":27},"loe":{"bld":11,"inv":8,"size":12,"activity":17,"total":48},"lots":{"total":92,"total_active":0}},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-106.75845,34.659846]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"id":120715,"name":"Jardin de Belen","status":"Act 1Q05","show":false,"territoryId":2002},"metrics":{"bld":{"type":"Unknown","count":{"prod":0,"custom":0}},"inv":{"fut":0,"vdl":6,"mod":4,"fin":14,"uc":18,"total":36},"loe":{"bld":15,"inv":3,"size":6,"activity":2,"total":26},"lots":{"total":200,"total_active":0}},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-106.81188,34.649485]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"id":120746,"name":"Schollander Heights","status":"Act 3Q05","show":false,"territoryId":2002},"metrics":{"bld":{"type":"Unknown","count":{"prod":0,"custom":0}},"inv":{"fut":0,"vdl":2,"mod":1,"fin":5,"uc":2,"total":8},"loe":{"bld":8,"inv":12,"size":15,"activity":4,"total":39},"lots":{"total":44,"total_active":0}},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-106.80648,34.646378]}}]
```

note, even when i remove the brackets inside data, the error goes away but no data shows up
I am open to different pie charts if someone has a recommendation. thanks

Update
plunker
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oiDNmbX9AdEPzJWvFprR?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module("mainModule", ['angles']);
  var MainController = function($scope,chartData,chartConfig) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.data = chartData;      
    vm.doughnutOptions = chartConfig.doughnutOptions;
};



    app.controller("MainController", MainController);
```

Comment: Which chart library are you using?

Comment: sorry, angular angles with chart.js

Comment: @texas697 - could you set up a fiddle? Its a bit messy to figure out the code you use to convert your json to the angular model?

Comment: Sure thing. Give me about a hour

Comment: there you go! it is setup

Comment: There is no error in your demo.

Comment: Have you copied the error message? it´s kind of confusing it contains a weird typo
[{{subdivision.chartBldArry}}] starting at [{subdivision.chartBldArry}}]
one contains 1 { at the start, the 2nd contains 2

Comment: ok, sorry, i tried removing the expression brackets. i just put them back so the error message appears. also i have no problem using another chart library. all i need it a doughnut or pie chart

Comment: crap, wrong data. sorry! few minutes

Comment: ok, your good to go. sorry about that. got a lot going on. thanks for your patience

Comment: figured out it was spelling of the chart arrays in the json vs the html. I had char*** instead of chart***  i do give you credit if i hadnt have had to redo my plunker i would have never caught it. post it as answer